# UITableView inside UIView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I have a `View Controller` , In which i want to add a `UIView` as a `SubView`.

Now i further want to add a `TableView in side my UIView` ?

I am basically avoiding to add a new View Controller and Just want to work with SubViews.

My Query is :

1. Do i need to create a `XIB file` for this kind of interface (as i am working with storyboards)
2. Do i need to create a separate `Class` for `delegate methods of tableView`? If YES then how will it look like?

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: i am thinking a way to implement this . in iPhone

Comment: You should start with reading docs for UITableView and investigating samples https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO for both questions:

1) You can create the interface using a XIB or creating the hierarchy programmatically. Feel free to use the method you like.

2) No, you can (and you should) set your current ViewController as delegate and datasource of the table view. To implement the delegates and datasource methods I suggest you read the [Apple documentation](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html&ei=hFo1U87MI4i0hAeR1YHoDw&usg=AFQjCNEgcK4nssHE-I9TLFEVsfyuns-hTw&bvm=bv.63808443,d.ZG4)

Comment: Agreed with your suggestions. I know how to set the delegate and datasource of the VC just having a doubt .
Thanks for the answer

Comment: Actually you should NOT use the view controller to implement the delegate and datasource, even though apple uses it in their examples. It is violating the Single Responsibility Principle. http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2013/06/ios-app-architecture-and-tdd-1.html and http://bendyworks.com/geekville/articles/2014/2/single-responsibility-principle-ios for further information.

Comment: I've understood your point, but when you decide to use a system to develop, you have to accept and follows what the system says. Apple suggest you to use your view controller ad delegate and datasource and you should do it, since other programmers that follows the same system search them in the ViewControllers. The normal MVC theory wants them implemented in a different way, but are not in the theory case, you are in the practical case so you have to model your theory to embrace the system you are using.
But I understand your point and it is a good point indeed.

Comment: Apple does not say this or that. they just put example code for certain aspect online. and they make everything else simple. and no, I don't have to follow them as it is easy to do it better. even interface builder is prepared to do so. cocoa encourage to use mvc, while most examples are poorly mvc. If you want to follow, do so. I want to gain better skills and reusable code.

Answer (score 0):

you can add table view programatically and add it into UIView

```
[yourView addSubView:tblView];
```

Comment: ya i know this , but what if i want to have some more UI elements with table view ?

Comment: then make an separate class of Custom cell by which you can add UIElement according to you.